# How do you test a cake or brownie with a toothpick?

Tags: baking

When it comes to the toothpick test for checking cake and brownie doneness, where do I poke the toothpick?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The center of the pan is usually the last part to cook.  So, test the center.